Can I be sure that the application/json header is only set on ajax requests?
I need to distinguish browser requests from ajax requests and can see that when making a request via a form submission in regular HTML, I get the following value for the accept header:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7

Whereas with my ajax request I get:
application/json

Here is the code for my ajax request:
fetch("/auth/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: emailInput.value,
        pword: pwordInput.value,
    }),
});

This means that on my server I can do a check like:
if (!req.headers.accept.includes("application/json")) {
    req.flash("loginError", "Please enable JavaScript or use a browser that supports JavaScript to continue.");
    return res.redirect("/auth/login");
}

However, my question is if this a reliable strategy accross all browsers/versions to distinguish ajax requests from javascript and browser requests or if i should do something else? Is it consistent what the accept header will look like for all browser requests or could it be that a browser will include the application/json inside the accept header as well making my strategy not work?

Why don't you add your own custom header? Your method with the accept header also reliably works.

Is that allowed? I thought it wasn't possible because of cors only allow specific headers?

Yes, it's allowed. You configure what CORS allows.

Ok I'll look into that thank you
